# How can i get the colon in output of jsp while using JSON object?

Tags: json

Here i am using Json . By default it will be spilt by colon. but in my output i need the colon in my jsp page.How ever if i use colon it will be splited....
how can i avoid it....

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

> JSONObject entity = new JSONObject();
>
> ...
>
> String result = entity.toString();

result will be entity with escaped special chars